# MS VS 2013 Keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

With MS Visual Studio 2013, what are the keyboard shortcuts (if any) for:

- "Float"
- "Move to Main Document Group"

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are no default shortcuts for these commands. You can assign your own shortcuts in Visual Studio keyboard option to **Window.Float** and **Window.MoveToMainDocumentGroup** commands.